# Extending classes in C++ (System.Windows.Forms.TextBox)

Tags: winforms, c++-cli, derived-class

In C#, I often like to create a custom class called "IntTextBox" which only allows valid integers to exist in the "Text" property.

```
public class IntTextBox : TextBox
{
    string origin = "0";
    //A string to return to if the user-inputted text is not an integer.
    public IntTextBox()
    {
        Text = "0";
        TextChanged += new EventHandler(IntTextBox_TextChanged);
    }
    private void IntTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int temp;
        if(int.TryParse(Text,out temp))
        //If the value of "Text" can be converted into an integer.
        {
            origin = Text;
            //"Save" the changes to the "origin" variable.
        }
        else
        {
            Text = origin;
            //Return to the previous text value to remove invalidity.
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to imitate this in C++ and no errors are apparent, however when I attempt to add it to my form, Visual Studio says "Failed to load item 'IntTextBox'. It will be removed from the toolbox. This is the code I've tried so far.

```
public ref class IntTextBox : public System::Windows::Forms::TextBox
{
    public:
        IntTextBox()
        {
            Text = "0";
            TextChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &AIMLProjectCreator::IntTextBox::IntTextBox_TextChanged);
        }
    private:
        String^ origin = "0";
        System::Void IntTextBox_TextChanged(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
        {
            int temp;
            if (int::TryParse(Text, temp))
            {
                origin = Text;
            }
            else
            {
                Text = origin;
            }
        }
};
```

Comment: This is not C++ - retagged.

Comment: @in what way is it not C++? I'm trying to get this to work in C++.

Comment: It's C++/CLI, which is the Microsoft language that bridges standard C++ and C# (and the rest of .NET).

Comment: I *think* I repro.  You can debug design-time exception by starting VS again and use Debug > Attach to Process to attach to the first one.  Let it break on all CLR exceptions.  When I try it, it fails with a FileLoadException because is unhappy to load the unverifiable EXE assembly.  The workaround is to spin this class off in its own class library project, add a reference to it in your main project.

Comment: @Hans: Ahh yes, mixed-mode EXE is not position-independent, so it can't be loaded into the address space of Visual Studio the way that a pure MSIL EXE can.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your C++/CLI project is set up to produce a mixed-mode assembly, which is partly CPU-independent CIL (MSIL), and partly native code.  The native code is architecture-specific, which means you have to recompile it for either 32-bit (x86) or 64-bit (x64).

If the C++/CLI DLL is a different architecture from Visual Studio, the designer can't load it.

Try compiling for x86 in order to use design mode.

Comment: Thanks, but the code exists within the same project, I'm not trying to compile it separately and then import it.

Comment: @Rariolu; Doesn't matter, it still has to get loaded into Visual Studio in order for the designer to place it.  And only a 32-bit DLL can be loaded into Visual Studio.  64-bit can't, for C++/CLI there is no "AnyCPU" (unless you use `/clr:pure`), and as Hans points out in his comment, an EXE can't either.

Answer (score 0):

```
#pragma once
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
namespace wfext {
    public ref class IntTextBox : TextBox {
        String^ origin = "0";
        //A string to return to if the user-inputted text is not an integer.
    public: IntTextBox(){
        this->Text = "0";
        TextChanged += gcnew EventHandler(this, &IntTextBox::IntTextBox_TextChanged);
    }
    private: void IntTextBox_TextChanged(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e){
        int temp;
        if (int::TryParse(this->Text, temp)){   //If the value of "Text" can be converted into an integer.
            origin = this->Text;
            //"Save" the changes to the "origin" variable.
        }
        else{
            this->Text = origin;
            //Return to the previous text value to remove invalidity.
        }
    }
    };
}
```